# Querying SQLite Dates with different formats

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have dates in a SQLite table that are stored in non-standard date formats. I need to be able to query by them. For example, records for today's date are `11/1/2015` in the "date" column and `2015-11-1` in the "sortDate" column.

My query needs to return the count of records from the past week. The following returns nothing: `SELECT count(*) FROM Grades WHERE sortDate BETWEEN '2015-10-24' AND '2015-11-02'`

I also get nothing from `SELECT count(*) FROM Grades WHERE sortDate BETWEEN datetime('now', '-7 days') AND datetime('now')`

I think the issue is that my dates are not padded to always have 2 month or date digits, as in `YYYY-MM-DD`. How would I query this existing data with these non-standard formats?

Answer (score 1):

As Sqlite [doesn't have a date type](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) you will need to do string comparison to achieve this. For that to work you need to reverse the order - eg from dd/MM/yyyy to yyyyMMdd, using something like

```
where substr(column,7)||substr(column,4,2)||substr(column,1,2) 
      between '20101101' and '20101130'
```

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but my dates are sometimes `YYYY-MM-DD` and sometimes `YYYY-M-D`, depending on whether the month and date are 1 or 2 digits. So I won't always know the index for the substring.

Comment: can you just add 0 value if month or date smaller than 10? but before that i need to know how you get the date

Comment: How would I do that in the query? Or would I have to get a list of String results, convert those to dates in java, and then write a function to "filter" that list and return the count? I was hoping I could do all of this in the sqlite query.

Comment: how you insert the values? then just modify that value

Comment: This is an existing application and I need to be able to query the data as it exists, so modifying how the values are inserted would not work for existing data.

Comment: oh. then you should do it your way, get the date first, convert it in java, then query again using converted date

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting all date strings from the database and dealing with them in Java. I just needed the count of how many entries there were within the past week, past two weeks, and past month. I wrote the following function to return those counts based on a provided ArrayList of strings.

```
Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar tomorrow = (Calendar) today.clone();
        tomorrow.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

        Calendar backDateWeek = (Calendar) today.clone();
        backDateWeek.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
        Calendar backDateTwoWeeks = (Calendar) today.clone();
        backDateTwoWeeks.add(Calendar.DATE, -14);
        Calendar backDateMonth = (Calendar) today.clone();
        backDateMonth.add(Calendar.DATE, -30);

        ArrayList<Calendar> calendarList = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
        Calendar tmpCal;
        String strSplit[];
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
        int countWeek = 0;
        int countTwoWeeks = 0;
        int countMonth = 0;
        for (String dateStr : dateStrings) {
            strSplit = dateStr.split("/");
            month = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[0]) - 1;
            day = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[1]);
            year = Integer.parseInt(strSplit[2]);
            tmpCal = Calendar.getInstance();
            tmpCal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            tmpCal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            tmpCal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);

            if (tmpCal.after(backDateWeek) && tmpCal.before(tomorrow)) {
                countWeek++;
                countTwoWeeks++;
                countMonth++;
            } else if (tmpCal.after(backDateTwoWeeks) && tmpCal.before(tomorrow)) {
                countTwoWeeks++;
                countMonth++;
            } else if (tmpCal.after(backDateMonth) && tmpCal.before(tomorrow)) {
                countMonth++;
            }
        }

        int[] countsArray = new int[3];
        countsArray[0] = countWeek;
        countsArray[1] = countTwoWeeks;
        countsArray[2] = countMonth;

        return countsArray;
```